# Dynamically Change RxJS Interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable `obs` with an interval `125*variable`, completing an action ever 0.125 seconds. The value of `variable` will change dynamically throughout my program.

```
 obs = interval(125*variable).pipe(
    takeWhile(() => this.t < moment('2019-04-16T18:00:00')),
    tap(() => {
      if (!this.isPaused) {
        this.t.add(1, 'minutes'); this.time = this.t.format('LLL');
      }
    }),
    map(() => moment(this.time))
  );
```

How can I change my observable's interval to use the correct/updated `variable` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution could be like this -

Because `"variable"` is changing throughout the program. So we first have a BehaviorSubject which will wrap `"variable"` as an observable and BehaviorSubject will be used to emit the next value for `variable` -

```
const variable$ = new BehaviorSubject(1); //you can set initial value as per your need

updateVariable(newValue) {
  this.variable$.next(newValue);
}

this.variable$.pipe(
  switchMap(val => interval(125 * val),
  //now apply your various operators chain as per your need
  takeWhile(),...
  tap(),...
  map()...
).subscribe()
```

Having this will ensure to start your interval (with 125 * variable) on the emission of each new `'variable'` value, canceling the previous interval (switchMap will take care of it). Only subscribe once [there is no need to resubscribe].

Answer (score 5):

So your problem is that you don't want to have fixed interval but rather after each emission start all over with `125*variable`.

You can wrap `interval()` inside `defer()` and resubscribe after each emission to trigger its callback. This means that after each emission the `interval` Observable will complete and `repeat()` will re-subscribe to it immediately:

```
const obs = defer(() => interval(125 * variable)).pipe(
  take(1),
  repeat(),
  takeWhile(...),
  tap(...),
  map(...)
);
```

Comment: use timer instead of interval and you wont need the take(1)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for this problem with similar problem.
Dynamically change interval value inside task that is call by interval.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  msgs = [];
  monitorDevInterval$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(2000); // start with 2 sec

  ngOnInit() {
    this.msgs.push("Starting");

    this.monitorDevInterval$
      .pipe(
        switchMap( value => interval( value ) ), 
        tap(n => {
          this.msgs.push("Interval tick " + n.toString() + ' ' +  this.monitorDevInterval$.getValue());
          // Update interval with new value
          this.monitorDevInterval$.next( this.monitorDevInterval$.getValue() + 1000 );
        })
      )      
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the timer observable creator, which will cause a new emission after each redefined newInterval, the interval$ subject captures
the newly defined interval

```
const interval$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
let newInterval = 1000;

this.interval$.pipe(
  switchMap((duration) => timer(duration)),
  tap(() =>  this.interval$.next(this.newInterval))
).subscribe();

changeInterval(interv: number) {
  this.newInterval = interv;
}
```